# Merge multiple multi-page tiff images to a single tiff C#

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, drawing, tiff

In my scenario I have 3 or more multi-page tiff images which I need to merge into a single tiff image.

Below is the the code I have tried. It merges in to a single tiff image but only with first page of all tiff images.

```
private static void MergeTiff(string[] sourceFiles)
{
    string[] sa = sourceFiles;
    //get the codec for tiff files
    ImageCodecInfo info = null;
    foreach (ImageCodecInfo ice in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders())
        if (ice.MimeType == "image/tiff")
            info = ice;

    //use the save encoder
    Encoder enc = Encoder.SaveFlag;

    EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters(1);
    ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);

    Bitmap pages = null;

    int frame = 0;

    foreach (string s in sa)
    {
        if (frame == 0)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"C:\Data_Warehouse\SVNRepository\CD.BNS.W5555.LT45555C.D180306.T113850.Z0101\", s)));
            pages = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);

            var appDataPath = @"C:\Data_Warehouse\SVNRepository\Tiffiles\";
            var filePath = Path.Combine(appDataPath, Path.GetRandomFileName() + ".tif");

            //save the first frame
            pages.Save(filePath, info, ep);
        }
        else
        {
            //save the intermediate frames
            ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);

            try
            {
                MemoryStream mss = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"C:\Data_Warehouse\SVNRepository\CD.BNS.W5555.LT45555C.D180306.T113850.Z0101\", s)));
                Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(mss);
                pages.SaveAdd(bm, ep);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //LogError(e, s);
            }
        }

        if (frame == sa.Length - 1)
        {
            //flush and close.
            ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);
            pages.SaveAdd(ep);

        }

        frame++;
    }

}
```

I need to join multiple tiff images with all pages from each tiff image. Please advise!

Thanks

**EDIT**: Updated from below answer

```
if (frame == 0)
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"C:\OMTest\Working\", s)));
                pages = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);

                var appDataPath = @"C:\Data_Warehouse\SVNRepository\Tiffiles\";
                var filePath = Path.Combine(appDataPath, Path.GetRandomFileName() + ".tif");

                //save the first frame
                pages.Save(filePath, info, ep);

                //Save the second frame if any
                int frameCount1 = pages.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
                if (frameCount1 > 1)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i < frameCount1; i++)
                    {
                        ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);
                        pages.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, i);
                        pages.SaveAdd(pages, ep);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //save the intermediate frames
                ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);
                try
                {
                    MemoryStream mss = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"C:\OMTest\Working\", s)));
                    Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(mss);
                    int frameCount = bm.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
                    for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++)
                    {
                        bm.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, i);
                        pages.SaveAdd(bm, ep);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //LogError(e, s);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to [select the active frame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.selectactiveframe?view=netframework-4.7.2) to ensure you are getting all pages on the TIFF. In your code you need to [get the count of frames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.getframecount?view=netframework-4.7.2) and loop through these.

The code in your else block might look something like this:

```
MemoryStream mss = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"C:\Data_Warehouse\SVNRepository\CD.BNS.W5555.LT45555C.D180306.T113850.Z0101\", s)));
Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(mss);
int frameCount = bm.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
for(int i=0;i<frameCount;i++){
    bm.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, i);
    pages.SaveAdd(bm, ep);
}
```

You may have to tweak it as I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code worked perfectly fine although I had to tweak a little. Added a changed code in edit section for anyone's reference.

Answer (score 1):

The given code works great to merge single-page TIFF files into a single multi-page TIFF, however, if there are multi-page TIFF files as sources, it will only merge their first page in the resulting TIFF file: the other ones will be discarded.

Since we couldn't find any working samples that could work around this issue, we ended up coding a small C# helper class, which later became a full-fledged multi-platform console application written in .NET Core 2 and C#. We called the project ***MergeTIFF*** and we released the whole source code on GitHub under GNU v3 license, so that everyone else can use it as well; we also released the binaries for Windows and Linux (32-bit and 64-bit).

Here's the relevant excerpt of the C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;

namespace MergeTiff.NET
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A small helper class to handle TIFF files
    /// </summary>
    public static class TiffHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Merges multiple TIFF files (including multipage TIFFs) into a single multipage TIFF file.
        /// </summary>
        public static byte[] MergeTiff(params byte[][] tiffFiles)
        {
            byte[] tiffMerge = null;
            using (var msMerge = new MemoryStream())
            {
                //get the codec for tiff files
                ImageCodecInfo ici = null;
                foreach (ImageCodecInfo i in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders())
                    if (i.MimeType == "image/tiff")
                        ici = i;

                Encoder enc = Encoder.SaveFlag;
                EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters(1);

                Bitmap pages = null;
                int frame = 0;

                foreach (var tiffFile in tiffFiles)
                {
                    using (var imageStream = new MemoryStream(tiffFile))
                    {
                        using (Image tiffImage = Image.FromStream(imageStream))
                        {
                            foreach (Guid guid in tiffImage.FrameDimensionsList)
                            {
                                //create the frame dimension 
                                FrameDimension dimension = new FrameDimension(guid);
                                //Gets the total number of frames in the .tiff file 
                                int noOfPages = tiffImage.GetFrameCount(dimension);

                                for (int index = 0; index < noOfPages; index++)
                                {
                                    FrameDimension currentFrame = new FrameDimension(guid);
                                    tiffImage.SelectActiveFrame(currentFrame, index);
                                    using (MemoryStream tempImg = new MemoryStream())
                                    {
                                        tiffImage.Save(tempImg, ImageFormat.Tiff);
                                        {
                                            if (frame == 0)
                                            {
                                                //save the first frame
                                                pages = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(tempImg);
                                                ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);
                                                pages.Save(msMerge, ici, ep);
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                //save the intermediate frames
                                                ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);
                                                pages.SaveAdd((Bitmap)Image.FromStream(tempImg), ep);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        frame++;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (frame >0)
                {
                    //flush and close.
                    ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);
                    pages.SaveAdd(ep);
                }

                msMerge.Position = 0;
                tiffMerge = msMerge.ToArray();
            }
            return tiffMerge;
        }
    }
}
```

For additional info and/or to download it, you can take a look at the following resources that we published to better document the whole project:

- [MergeTIFF on GitHub](https://github.com/Darkseal/MergeTIFF)
- [Specifications, dependencies and other info](https://www.ryadel.com/en/mergetiff-asp-net-core-merge-tiff-tif-files-multi-page-open-source-free-download/)