# C# merge tiff files without increasing file size 2-3x

Tags: c#, image, tiff

I need to merge single tiff files into one. There are many examples online that look all pretty similiar, like this one [Merge multiple multi-page tiff images to a single tiff C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54284384/merge-multiple-multi-page-tiff-images-to-a-single-tiff-c-sharp).

The Problem is, all of these solutions double or triple the combined filesize of the individual single page files.

I tried just an online tiff merging tool and the file size didnt go up, so i know its possible.

Anybody know how to keep the file size down in c# code?

This is the code i use.

```
Bitmap firstImage = new Bitmap(images[0].bitmap);

encoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.SaveFlag;
encoderInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()[3];
encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1); //(2)
encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(encoder, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);
// encoderParameters.Param[1] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Compression, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT4);

firstImage.Save(path, encoderInfo, encoderParameters);


encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(encoder, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);

// Add the remaining images to the tiff
for (int i = 1; i < images.Count; i++)
{
    firstImage.SaveAdd(images[i].bitmap, encoderParameters);
}

// Close out the file
encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(encoder, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);
firstImage.SaveAdd(encoderParameters);
```

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I think I see the problem. TIFF is a compressed format, and C# is converting the files into uncompressed bitmaps, then saving them as a TIFF. I'd look for EncoderParameter options to set the compression ratio

Comment: Yes it was the compression. Now the multipage tiff is even smaller than the combined filesizes of the singular tiffs. I edited my post to show the solution, in case anyone finds it at some point.

Comment: Don't edit your question to include the solution - write an answer. It's perfectly fine to answer your own questions on Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer :)
need to add

**ep.Param[1] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT4);**

Comment: Please explain why this answer works, and why you pick that particular option.